# Jquery working with two or more variables at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having code like this:

```
 var input = $('input');
            var select = $('select');
            var text = $('textarea');
            var name = $('#name');
            var email = $('#email');
            var phone = $('#phone');
            var subject = $('#subject');
            var message = $('#message');
            var sum = $('#sum');

            (input, select, text).focus(function(){

                $(this).css('z-index', 100)
            });
```

When input element is focus, it needs to change z-index to a 100, and non focused elements need to change their z-index to 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `add` method to concatentate jQuery objects, and the `not` method to exclude one:

```
var input_select_text = input.add(select).add(text);

input_select_text.focus(function(){
  $(this).css('z-index', 100);
  input_select_text.not(this).css('z-index', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code:

```
$('input').focusin(function() {
  $(this).css('z-index', '100');
});
$('input').focusout(function() {
  $(this).css('z-index', '1');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(input, select, text).focus(function(){
    (input, select, text).css('z-index', 1);
    $(this).css('z-index', 100);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried that code? Do you know what is the result of the comma operator? `(input, select, text)` will result in `text`, so you are effectively binding the event handler only to the `text` element.